Any advice for running websockets/ws on Node.js mobile, ideally using Flutter as the front end?
I have had great success running websockets/ws on Node.js under macOS, which I use to coordinate remote Flutter apps running on iOS and Android mobile phones.
I would like to explore the possibility of running websockets/ws on Node.js mobile under iOS and under Android, ideally using Flutter as the front end.
The objective is to avoid using a "standard" cloud-like server (hosted by some cloud server on macOS or Windows or Linux) and to use a mobile phone to coordinate other mobile phones through websockets/ws.
Why? Because the client prefers to do things this way.
Any caveats before diving in?
Thanks.
I'm just curious to know whether this is even possible and, if possible, to learn about any cautionary considerations.

First thing -> is the 'ws' package compatible with the node.js mobile, i don't think it is, Networking on mobile is handled differently from desktops and server, you probably have to create a custom build or tweak 'ws' package a little.
Second thing -> how you are going to manage the Dynamic IPs, Phone often have changing IP addresses, so connecting directly b/w devices is tricky
and Phones switches b/w Wi-Fi and mobile network often, which might cause the Websocket connections to drop or become unstable.
Third thing -> Let's say you find/build a compatible package and you have sorted the dyanmic IP problem, how you are going to handle SSL/TSS certificates on your phone, wss:// is must, unless you are on local network 
Bottom Line -> It's possible to set this up, but it's a bit outside the norm, so just be ready for some challenges. ,
Try considering the WebRTC for peer-to-peer connections, with the TURN server it is pretty stable solution

Excellent observations, @saumyakr. Exactly the kind of wise comments I was hoping for. I'll pursue all of your points. Thank you very much.

Thanks to your comments, I quickly found this, which might be useful to others exploring this topic: link
